# error message of firebase version [0.6.2]

Tags: java, firebase, android-studio

I am trying to have a chat room using firbase.

But error occurred when I have put the following code

```
compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:0.6.2'
```

Here is the build.gradle app module

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "26.0.1"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.kenny.bettingai"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile files('libs/J-Excel-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar')
compile files('libs/jxl.jar')

compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:0.6.2'
}
```

here is the error message

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 15 cannot be smaller than 
version 16 declared in library [com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:0.6.2] 
C:\Users\Kenny\.android\build- 
cache\32db91379d86947a54b2b6b2ac61dd84080343b4\output\AndroidManifest.xml
Suggestion: use tools:overrideLibrary="com.firebase.ui" to force usage
```

Can anyone tell me what the way to force override Library?

Answer (score 0):

As you can see from this error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 15 cannot be smaller than 
version 16 declared in library [com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:0.6.2]
```

it means that `com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:0.6.2` is using minSdkVersion 16 but you're using minSdkVersion 15. So, you need to either change your minSdkVersion to **16** or add `tools:overrideLibrary="com.firebase.ui"` to your **AndroidManifest.xml** something like this:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.myapp"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <uses-sdk tools:overrideLibrary="com.firebase.ui"/>

</manifest>
```

---

Note: you should not force the library to use minSdkVersion 15 because the library probably won't work with it.